# In perl pattern matching..how to exclude the \n character from pattern

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I am new to perl and writing my first few programs and using its pattern matching abilities. I am reading a file into array like this:

```
@list=<file>
```

Then indexing each line of array by $list[0..9] etc, and when I match it against a pattern, the `$list[0]` includes `\n` character, hence the match fails. So if `($string =~ $list[0])` fails though without `\n` character in pattern it would match.

How do I tell pattern matcher to not consider the `\n` character from pattern?

Thanks

Comment: A typical regex would not consider the newline by default. For example, `/foo/` or even `/^foo$/`. Show us your regular expression. Otherwise, the only advice we can give is (1) remove the newline from the string, or (2) add a newline to the regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shave the line ends from the array after reading:

```
@lines = …;
chomp @lines;
```

Now `@lines` contains the lines without line ends. See [`perldoc chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the `\n` from your lines you can:

```
chomp $list[0]
```

see `perldoc -f chomp` for the details.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good opportunity to get to know how Perl modules work.

You can for example use [Perl6::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Perl6-Slurp-0.03/Slurp.pm) which will both a) parse the file b) put the contents in an array c) remove the newline characters for you.

For example:

```
use Perl6::Slurp;
my @lines = slurp '<:utf8', 'filename', {chomp=>"\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match with the `\n`:

```
if ( $list[0] =~ "$string\n")
```

Or if you want the \n to be optional:

```
if ( $list[0] =~ /$string\n?/ )
```